# How to Properly Typeset a Set of Nonclosed Quotations

Tags: typography, csquotes, quotation

I would like to properly typeset (with `csquotes`, if possible) the nonclosed red quotations produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\parskip 10pt
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}

\textbf{\color{red}{`` \hskip -3pt ` \hskip -3pt ``My friend,'' he asked, ``how may I properly typeset (i.e., without the negative hskips) the two sets of quotations in red?''}}

\vskip 5pt

\textbf{\color{red}{`` \hskip -3pt ` \hskip -3pt ``This is the second of the two sets.''}}

\vskip 5pt

\textbf{\enquote{\enquote{This nested and closed set of quotations is however, properly typeset, I think.}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have not been able to properly typeset the red sets of quotations with `csquotes` as they are not closed---so I forced it with some `\hskip`s to give an idea of how I would like the output to look like. The last set of quotations (in black), I believe, are properly typeset.

If someone would show me how the quotations in red may be properly typeset without forcing, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intended meaning of the first and second paragraph. It is a quote that starts with direct speech in quotes, but why is there a single quote in between? Is it doubly nested and both levels are unclosed? My confusion might also indicate that this is not the most clear and understandable way of using quotes, and maybe the max 2 level `\enquote{\enquote{}}` version is preferred.

Comment: @Marijn I am trying to type something directly from a book; the quotes in the MWE reflect part of a flowing set of quotations in that book that I am trying to reproduce.

Comment: I see, that makes the requirement more clear. However I still think that more than one nesting level is too much and makes the quote difficult to parse, especially when the quote characters are directly adjacent. Maybe you can make it easier for your readers by choosing a different markup, like indentation instead of quote characters for the first quotation level (this is what `\begin{quote}\end{quote}` does by default), or even skipping the secondary source and quoting the original directly?

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your comment, but it is important in this case that I mimic as much as possible the exact flow of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** Adding some inner space.

Define a new style like

```
%% *********************************************** added
%%  Some horizontal spacing
\newcommand{\innerspace}{\hskip0.3em}  % set inner spaces in em units

\DeclareQuoteStyle[noclosed]{dblquote}
{{\textquotedblleft\innerspace\textquoteleft\innerspace}}  %opening outer mark
{} %closing outer mark
[0.05em]
{\textquotedblleft}     %opening inner mark
{\textquotedblright}    %closing inner mark

%% ***********************************************
```

Use the command `\innerspace` to set the inner space between the quotes: `\hskip<len>`. (Use `em` units!)

[image: x]

[image: zxx]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % only if using  pdflatex

%% *********************************************** added
%%  Some horizontal spacing
\newcommand{\innerspace}{\hskip0.3em}  % set inner spaces in em units   

\DeclareQuoteStyle[noclosed]{dblquote}
{{\textquotedblleft\innerspace\textquoteleft\innerspace}}  %opening outer mark
{} %closing outer mark
[0.05em]
{\textquotedblleft}     %opening inner mark
{\textquotedblright}    %closing inner mark

%% ***********************************************

\begin{document}
\parskip 10pt
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}

\textbf{\enquote{\enquote{This nested and closed set of quotations is however, properly typeset, I think.}}}


{{`` \hskip -3pt ` \hskip -3pt ``My friend,'' he asked, ``how may I properly typeset (i.e., without the negative hskips) the two sets of quotations in red?''}}

\vskip 5pt

{{`` \hskip -3pt ` \hskip -3pt ``This is the second of the two sets.''}}

{\bfseries\large With the new quote style}

\setquotestyle[noclosed]{dblquote} % use the new style <<<<
\enquote{%
    \enquote{My friend,} he asked, \enquote{how may I properly typeset (i.e., without the negative hskips) the two sets of quotations in red?}
}   

\enquote{%
\enquote{This is the second of the two sets.}
}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for, I'm sorry. I am trying to typeset (as exactly as possible) the quotations as they already are shown in red. I am trying to find out if this is possible with `csquotes`, and if so, how to do it---not, unfortunately, to rewrite them.

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch Please see the updates answer. I am reproducing the red quotes (now in black).

Comment: Almost there; thank you. However, in the opening set of five quotations, there should be a space between quote marks 2 and 3 and a similar space between quote marks 3 and 4. In the document I am typesetting, these spaces are of equal measure, although in my makeshift MWE attempt with the `hskip`s, they appear not exactly so. Would you be able to add these two equally measured spaces between quote marks 2 and 3 and quote marks 3 and 4 in your answer? Many thanks.

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch Any specific width?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but if you specify some reasonable length to display the answer with---as long as I can see how you did it so that I could make an adjustment if I had to, that would be most helpful. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch Please see the last update. Added some space and a command so you can try different options from outside the style.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But when I run it, I get an error. Is it possible something got lost upon posting?

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch I reloaded the code just in case. Do it again on your side. What kind of error? I removed a lot of <<<<< it might have been the cause.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still get errors: (1) line 44 Missing $ inserted.};  (2) line 44 Extra}, or forgotten $.}; etc.

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch Try my code alone, as it is posted now. Not related : are you using pdflatex? See that the line `{\bfseries\large With the new quote style}` does not have extra chars or just remove it.

Comment: Yes; pdflatex. Still an error---the first line of errors: line 44: csquotes Error: Unbalanced group or invalid nesting.}. I presume, though, the code is running fine on your end.

Comment: Also, I tried commenting out `{\bfseries\large With the new quote style}` and an error still results.---line 44 Missing $ inserted.}

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch It does. Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` and try  `\newcommand{\innerspace}{\hskip0.3em}`

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is already there; isn't it. And when I add `\newcommand{\innerspace}{\hskip0.3em}` , say, at line 6 in the preamble, I then get only two lines of errors, the first of which: `line 15 \innerspace already defined. \newcommand{\innerspace}{\;}` which refers me to the line of code `\newcommand{\innerspace}{\;}  % set inner spaces `.

Comment: @ Keep only one (perhaps with the hskip)  and delete or comment out the others adding % before the line.

Comment: Success: Adding `\newcommand{\innerspace}{\hskip0.3em}` at line 6 and commenting out `\newcommand{\innerspace}{\;}  % set inner spaces` at line 15, the code runs successfully. Please check to make sure the same happens for you and that the output produced is what is supposed to be produced. If so, then if you can replace the posted code with this and revise the posted output (if need be), that would be beneficial for any user who is interested in copying the code.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Samuel Bowditch Done! Thank you for your feedback! A pleasure.

Comment: Many thanks. @Simon Dispa